# C++ hash_map find() vs contains() performance

Tags: c++, performance, hashmap, std

What's the better option performance-wise if I want to check if an element is contained in a map and use it directly afterwards?

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> my_map;
int my_key;
```

Option 1:

```
if (const auto& iter = my_map.find(my_key); iter != my_map.end()) {
      const auto& value = iter->second;
}
```

Option 2:

```
if (my_map.contains(my_key)) {
      const auto& value = my_map.at(my_key);
}
```

For readability I prefer option 2. However, from my understanding Option 2 should be slower since there are two hashmap lookups.

Comment: You got it. Unfortunately the interface on the hash tables in C++ is not the best.

Comment: IMHO better: `try { const auto& value = my_map.at(my_key); } catch (const  std::out_of_range&) {}`

Comment: @273K Is the exception really going to be optimised away? If not, that's probably orders of magnitude worse than double tree traversal of second option.

Comment: @273K To me this looks like abusing exception as control flow, which is bad.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It depends on how often it's raised.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen There is no tree in `unordered_map` (only in `map`). At least, not in all mainstream implementations. It is generally implemented as an array of pointers pointing on linked-list nodes.

Comment: When in doubt, benchmark. Note that benchmarking picky stuff is **hard**, but if you build up experience benchmarking stuff like this that should be *easy*, when you get to the picky stuff you'll be in better shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

Using `find` is more efficient since there is only the one lookup being performed whereas the second option of using `contains` is less efficient because you have to also perform the `at` lookup.

Comment: *the compiler will likely optimise using contains and at to be the same as just find* - I'd be rather surprised to see such an optimization.

Comment: @Evg Sorry if what is said is inaccurate. What I meant was something more like "after optimisations, the two will perform about the same", which is a fair thing to say isn't it?

Comment: @ryley No, probably it is not. I'd be surprised if any C++ compiler folded the searches by `contains` and by `at` into one. This means that until compilers become smarter the non-trivial lookup will happen twice and that version should be about twice as slow.

Comment: @Evg Alright thank you for correcting me, I have removed the misinformation from my answer.

Comment: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xxfTeqGqK) is the generated code just to prove that the generated code with `contains` is bad (once can see that the `div`+`shr` is done more times with `option2`. `div`s are slow. However, hash-map are often slow because of cache-misses when they are big so the overhead of a `div` might not be so big in this case. Still, it is better to avoid it as much as possible. AFAIK, this is why `contains` was not available before : it is an anti-pattern regarding performance.